# passenger nginx module service name registration in ubuntu 12.04.2 lts

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

I am in need to register passenger nginx module as service in ubuntu and it need to start automatically, in the case of system reboot or shutdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last I found the solution:

```
wget -O init-deb.sh http://library.linode.com/assets/1139-init-deb.sh
mv init-deb.sh /etc/init.d/nginx
chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
/usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults


 sudo service nginx start    or sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
 sudo service nginx restart  or sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
 sudo service nginx reload   or sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
 sudo service nginx stop     or sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```

For more info visit:

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/installation/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin#sph_id7

Comment: If nginx was installed in the default location (e.g. via a package manager) before, you might get:  
  
    System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/nginx already exist.  

The solution to this is:  

    sudo update-rc.d -f nginx remove  

before  
  
    sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults

Answer (score 0):

There is a section for this in the Phusion Passenger for Nginx manual: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#nginx_init_script

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the above script supports ubuntu 8 as per the documentation. I think the script is in google code and its is legacy.